# How can I generate a vector resulting from two vectors with different length?

Tags: numpy, vector

I´m a beginner programmer in Python and my question is: if I have 2 vectors like these

```
arr1=np.array(1,2,3,4,5,6)
arr2=np.array(1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1)
```

Using the condition when a element in arr2=0, the element in arr1=-9, so the final vector should be

arr3=(1,2,-9,3,4,-9,-9,-9,5,6).

arr2 is a vector with 0 and 1 values only, the final vector should have the length of arr2.
arr1 can have less elements than arr1

Comment: try `np.insert(arr1, [2,5,6,7],-9)`  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html

Comment: I want to say that vector arr2 can be different, that´s is only an example, the conditional is important.

Comment: You could make an array the size of `arr2`, fill the `1's` with values from `arr1`, and fill to others with -9.  Just a matter of 'masked' indexing.

Comment: People will give the simplest answer, especially in comments.  Your example has to embody the more general case if that's important to you.

Comment: look at `np.nonzero(arr2==0)[0]`.  Those should be the insertion numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, sorry if I omitted some important details.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the [] when creating the 2 sample arrays.  It's a good idea to test the sample code:

```
In [86]: arr1=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
    ...: arr2=np.array([1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1])
```

My `insert` suggestion was wrong (untested from my phone):

```
In [87]: np.insert(arr1,[2,4,4,4],-9)
Out[87]: array([ 1,  2, -9,  3,  4, -9, -9, -9,  5,  6])
```

I should be able to derive that `[2,4,4,4]` from `arr2`, but it's easier to take the other approach.

Define an array like `arr2` but with 'fill' values:

```
In [88]: arr3 = np.zeros_like(arr2); arr3[:]=-9
```

Find the slots in `arr3` where `arr2` is 1 (not 0).  If the number match the length of `arr1` we can then copy:

```
In [89]: arr3[arr2==1]
Out[89]: array([-9, -9, -9, -9, -9, -9])
In [90]: arr3[arr2==1]=arr1

In [91]: arr3
Out[91]: array([ 1,  2, -9,  3,  4, -9, -9, -9,  5,  6])
```

I'm an experienced numpy programmer, so this is relatively easy.  But there's nothing here that isn't covered in the numpy documented basics.  It's just indexing assignment.